# How to convert a QString containing a hex value to an uint?

Tags: c++, qt, uint8t, qbytearray

```cpp
QString samp_buff[100];
QByteArray data;
uint8_t speed;

samp_buff[3] = data.toHex(); //I converted the QByteArray into a string
qDebug() << "read_every_data_"<< samp_buff[3];

speed = samp_buff[3].toUInt(); //Trying to convert the string to uint8_t
qDebug() << "Converted to UINT8" << speed;
```

Hi! I successfully got the `Qbytearray` value (data) stored in as a `QString` in the `samp_buff` array of strings, and also during the conversion of `QString` to `uint8_t` in the form of hex.

```
Data:  "\x07"       //QByteArray
read_every_data_ "07"    //QString
Converted to UINT8 7    //Uint8_t
```

Its working fine for this but the problem arises when this happens.

```
Data:  "\x0B"       //QByteArray
read_every_data_ "0b"    //QString
Converted to UINT8 0     //Uint8_t
```

Whenever the hex string has alphabets in it, the result of the conversion becomes zero.

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation of `QString::toUint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#toUInt) suggests, the signature of the function looks like this.

```cpp
uint QString::toUInt(bool *ok = nullptr, int base = 10) const
```

The second argument `base` is for specifying the base. To convert from hex strings, supply `16` to it.

```cpp
speed = samp_buff[3].toUInt(nullptr, 16);
```